# How to prove that $\lVert T \rVert $ equals $ \inf \{ C > 0 : \forall x \in E : \lVert T x\rVert \leq C\lVert x \rVert\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $L(E, F)$ be the space of bounded linear maps of
normed vector space $E$ into the normed vector space $F$ and for $T ∈ L(E, F)$.
$\left\|T\right\| := \sup \left\{ \left\|T x\right\| :\: x ∈ E,\, \left\|x\right\| \le 1\right\}$
the operator norm of $T$ .
Show that:

$\left\|T\right\| = \inf \left\{ C > 0 :\: \forall x \in E\, \left\|T x\right\| ≤ C\left\|x\right\|\right\}$
and for all $x \in E$ we have $\left\|T x\right\| ≤ \left\|T\right\|\left\|x\right\|$. Conclude from this that the operator norm is indeed a
norm and that $\left\|S ◦ T\right\| ≤ \left\|S\right\|\left\|T \right\|$ for all $T ∈ L(E, F)$ and $S ∈ L(F, G)$.

I tried it showing that the left side is less equal, then greater equal but that didn't work out at all.

Comment: Please show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\left\|T\right\|>0$ and set $A=\left\{C>0: \forall x\in E\, \left\|Tx\right\|\le C\left\|x\right\|\right\}$. We prove that $\left\|T\right\|\in A$. Choose $x\in E$. The inequality holds, for $x=0$. If $x\ne 0$, by definition of $\left\|T\right\|$, we have that $$\left\|T\left(\frac{x}{\left\|x\right\|}\right)\right\|\le \left\|T\right\|,$$
and by linearity of $T$, follows the desired inequality. Hence $\left\|T\right\|\in A$, whence $\inf A\le \left\|T\right\|$. Conversely, choose $C\in A$. By its definition,
$$\forall x\in E\quad\left\|Tx\right\|\le C\left\|x\right\|,$$
from where we take the supremum over all $\left\|x\right\|\le 1$, we attain $\left\|T\right\|\le C$. Therefore $\left\|T\right\|=\min A=\inf A$.

Note: In case where $\left\|T\right\|=0$, $A=\left(0,+\infty\right)$. So $\left\|T\right\|\notin A$ (the minimum value in $A$ is not attained). Nevertheless, $\left\|T\right\|=\inf A=0$.

Answer (score 0):

what you were trying to show is not wrong at all.

Let $||T||$ be defined with the $\sup$.
If $||Tx|| \leq c \:||x||$ for all  $x\in E $, then $||Ty|| \leq c$ for all $||y||\leq 1$ implies $||T||\leq c$ and this means that $$\inf\{c:||Tx||\leq c\:||x||\: \forall x \in E\}\geq ||T||.$$For $x\neq 0$ we have that $||Tx||=\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}||x||\leq ||T||\cdot||x||$ which implies $$||T||\geq\inf\{c:||Tx||\leq c\:||x||\: \forall x \in E\}$$and together we have shown the desired equivalence.

Now it remains to show that the norm properties are fullfilled.

Let now $T\in L(E,F), S\in L(F,G)$ and let $x\in E$ be arbitrary. Then we have$$||S\circ T(x)||=||S(Tx)||\leq ||S||\cdot ||Tx||\leq ||S||\cdot ||T||\cdot ||x||$$which yields $||S\circ T||\leq ||S||\cdot ||T||$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=\inf \{C\ge 0:\forall x\in E\,(\|Tx\|\le C\|x\|)\}.$

Then $\forall x\in E\,\forall n\in\Bbb N\,(\|Tx\|\le D(1+1/n)\|x\|\,).$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_n\in E$ with $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|Tx_n\|\ge \|T\|(1-1/n)$ by def'n of $\|T\|.$ Then $$\forall n\in \Bbb N\,(\,\|T\|(1-1/n)\le \|Tx_n\|\le D(1+1/n)\|x_n\|=D(1+1/n)\,)$$ implying $\|T\|\le D.$

By contradiction, if $\|T\|<D,$ then take any $H$ with $\|T\|<H<D.$ By def'n of $D$ take $x\in E$ with $\|Tx\|>H\|x\|.$  Now $x\ne 0$ because $\|Tx\|>H\|x\|\ge 0.$ So with $y=x/\|x\|$ we have $\|y\|=1$ and $\|Ty\|>H>\|T\|,$ contrary to the def'n of $\|T\|.$

So $\|T\|\ge D.$